# Defining !! operator using list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define the  !! using list comprehensions for a exercise I found, however seem like everything I try fails.

I have no idea how to do something like this, would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Why using *list* comprehension. List comprehension is normally used to generate a *list*, not a single value.

Answer (score 2):

A bit contrived perhaps, but what about this?

```
import Prelude hiding ( (!!) )

(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! i = head [ x | (x, j) <- zip xs [0 ..], i == j ]
```

Does the trick:

```
> [3, 5, 7, 11, 13] !! 2
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
(!!) xs i = head [ x | (x, n) <- ts, n == i]
  where ts = zip xs [0..]
```

but using `zip` feels like cheating